# Python list.pop() function does not work properly

Tags: python, list

The following is my code:

```
data = raw_input("Please enter your particulars in the format of name/age/address ->")

pro = data.split("/")

name = pro.pop(0)
age = pro.pop(1)
address = pro.pop()

print name
print age
print address
```

I understand that the index of a list goes by 0, 1, 2 but when i pop the age (which should be index 1 in the list), it gives me the address when it is printed. Likewise for the address it gives me the age instead. Can someone tell me what in the world is wrong with this thing?

Comment: `pop()` is completely unnecessary...

Comment: You `pro` list shrinks after `pop(0)`, so in the next pop operation you only have 2 elements i.e age and address so `pop(1)` gives you address and like wise.

Comment: This seems complicated. Consider doing `name, age, address = data.split("/")` and then you don't have to worry about indices at all.

Comment: Looking at the value of `pro` after each `pop` operation would have given you some idea of what was going on.

Answer (score 6):

Its because when you already pop index 0, other items shift left by 1 and so the index 1 moves at 0.

So you must do -

```
name = pro[0]
age = pro[1]
address = pro[2]
```

Answer (score 3):

Originally, the list is like this:

```
name  age  address
# 0    1      2
```

`age` is at index `1`. However, after you pop out `name`, it's

```
age address
# 0    1
```

`age` is now at index `0`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, `pop()` is completely unnecessary. However, it's important to understand what's happening when you were using it.

Calling `pop()` **removes and returns an item from a list, at a given index**. So, once the first item (at index 0) is popped, the new first item is the next item you're after (the item that was at index 1).

If you absolutely want to use `pop()`, the following works (but isn't recommended):

```
>>> name = pro.pop(0)
>>> age = pro.pop(0)
>>> address = pro.pop(0)
```

If you were then to print `pro`, you'd see the following:

```
>>> print pro
[]
```

Yep, an empty list (that has had all elements "popped" off).